# Converting DateTime String to Different Timezones in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

ok i have this following codes

```
$from = "Asia/Manila";
$to = "UTC";
$org_time = new DateTime("2012-05-15 10:50:00");
$org_time = $org_time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$conv_time = NULL;

$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone($from);
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone($to);
$myDateTime = new DateTime($org_time, $gmtTimezone);
$offset = $userTimezone->getOffset($myDateTime);
$conv_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $myDateTime->format('U') + $offset);
echo $conv_time;
```

with this code i want to convert `2012-05-15 10:50:00` to UTC and -8 Timezone(I used America/Vancouver) but it gives me a strange results

> ```
> Asia/Manila > UTC  
> 2012-05-15 19:50:00 = the correct is 2012-05-15 02:50
> ```

and for America/Vancouver

```
Asia/Manila > America/Vancouver 
2012-05-16 02:50:00 = the correct is 2012-05-14 19:50
```

where I went wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are making things way too hard. To convert between time zones, all you need to do is create a `DateTime` object with the proper source time zone, and then set the destination time zone via `setTimeZone()`.

```
$src_dt = '2012-05-15 10:50:00';
$src_tz =  new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila');
$dest_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver');

$dt = new DateTime($src_dt, $src_tz);
$dt->setTimeZone($dest_tz);

$dest_dt = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: yeah thank you, sorry I was trying to make things on my own in a hard way

Answer (score 2):

Don't use getOffset and calculate it by yourself, you should use [setTimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) for display

```
<?php
function conv($fromTime, $fromTimezone, $toTimezone) {

    $from = new DateTimeZone($fromTimezone);
    $to = new DateTimeZone($toTimezone);

    $orgTime = new DateTime($fromTime, $from);
    $toTime = new DateTime($orgTime->format("c"));
    $toTime->setTimezone($to);
    return $toTime;
}

$toTime = conv("2012-05-15 10:50:00", "Asia/Manila", "UTC");
echo $toTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// you can get 2012-05-15 02:50:00

echo "\n";

$toTime = conv("2012-05-16 02:50:00", "Asia/Manila", "America/Vancouver");
echo $toTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// you can get 2012-05-15 11:50:00

echo "\n";
```

Format "Y-m-d H:i:s" will use current local timezone (from php.ini or your ini_set), to show it with timezone, you can use format "c" or "r"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to subtract the offset instead of add it to me, from a quick glance at the results. It makes sense: say you're in GMT-5 and you want to convert your time to GMT. You wouldn't subtract 5 hours (time + offset), you would add 5 hours (time - offset). Granted, I am fairly tired, so I may be thinking backwards.

Comment: I tried it.. when i subtract the offset its correct with UTC, but the problem is when i do something like Asia/Manila > America/Vancouver they become the same

Comment: Do you mean they add up to 0? If so, you need to go through UTC first or add the offset from the original timezone to the offset from the target timezone. From what I can tell, your code just gets the offset from UTC, so when you do UTC-8 -> UTC+8 you'll end up getting the time minus itself.